# Split a string with double quotes -Java

Tags: java, split

I have a String

"OWIRH","ABCDHW","KR","Korea, Republic of","11","Seoul-t'ukpyolsi","Seoul","","37.598500","126.978300","HyosungITX","HyosungITX"

I want to split this string such as

```
String[]s 
s[0]="OWIRH"
s[1]="ABCDHW"
s[2]="KR"
s[3]="Korea, Republic of"
```

How do I apply such a (delimiter)split in java

Comment: yes ,the thing is the delimiter for splitting a string with a word in double quote

Comment: Do you want the quotes left in the result?

Comment: yes but I finally found it ,will update it on my answer

Comment: This data actually is csv data. So you should use csv library to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I got the split

```
String []ip_variables=line.split("\",");
```

This one worked for me

Comment: Doesn't this leave only one of the quotes in each result?

Comment: well quotes present in the result are not a issue,issue was to split a string with "someword" .I can remove the quotes on the result later .

Answer (score 1):

If you split on `"`, then every other string in the resulting list will be one you want; the others will be commas or leading/trailing blanks.  You can then build the array you want from that.

An alternative would be to split on `","` (not just the comma, but the comma in quotes); that would be very close to what you want, but the first item would have a leading `"` and the last a trailing one.

Comment: no ,i tried with "," but it doesnt give the result ,reason is with "," the result is not in correct form which I need ,as in case of US s[3] is "United States" but with korea it will split into two parts s[3]=korea and s[4]="republic of"

Comment: That is using just the comma as the string to split on; I'm suggesting using a string made up of 3 characters: a quote, a comma, and another quote.

Comment: Yes ,we quote + a comma .Can you please edit your answer please ,so I can just mark it as correct one

Answer (score 0):

You can split on comma surrounded by quotes, then replace leading/trailing quotation marks with empty strings. If you want to have it surrounded with quotes, you can easily add it after.